# How can I replace the Home link with an image?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I want to replace the *Home* link shown in breadcrumbs with an icon.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not an answer, but actually CSS is a very good solution for accessability reasons: A blind person with a screen reader should still get the text "Home" (e.g. with `class="visually-hidden"`) instead of the icon.

Comment: Even with JavaScript and CSS, there is still the need to change the markup used for the breadcrumb. Answers could describe how the breadcrumb markup can be altered.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not in the theme business but I suppose you can just override the twig template.

Assuming that the default template is in use:

```
[your_site]/core/themes/bartik/templates/classy/navigation/breadcrumb.html.twig
```

Just copy it to your theme templates folder and change it something like:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a breadcrumb trail.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - breadcrumb: Breadcrumb trail items.
 */
#}
{% if breadcrumb %}
  <nav class="breadcrumb" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
    <h2 id="system-breadcrumb" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Breadcrumb'|t }}</h2>
    <ol>
  {% for item in breadcrumb %}
      <li>
      {% if item.url %}
        {% if item.text == "Home" %}
          <a href="{{ item.url }}">
            <img src="some_src" alt="Some alt">
          </a>
        {% else %}
          <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
        {% endif %}
      {% else %}
          {{ item.text }}
      {% endif %}
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
    </ol>
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```